# How can I remove parentheses (both side) from tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**This is my script.py:**

```
from itertools import product
A = input().split()
B = input().split()
li1 = []
li2 = []
for i in A:
    li1.append(int(i))
for j in B:
    li2.append(int(j))

result = product(li1,li2)
print(tuple(result))
```

it gives me result like this `((1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4))`

But I want to result like this `(1, 3) (1, 4) (2, 3) (2, 4)`

How can I do this ?

Comment: Just print(result) ?

Comment: No, product() returns a generator object. Actually, gilch's answer looks correct and very simple.

Answer (score 6):

Unpack with a `*`

```
print(*result)
```

This will use the *contents* of the iterable as arguments to `print()`, instead of the whole thing as a single argument.